# Finding a probability of a process from a distribution of how long it takes before it happens

Tags: probability, statistics

Good day, 
I am looking to solve a statistical problem, namely of finding the probability of something happening, from the distribution of how long it takes before it happens.

So what I have is a system that can be in state S1, and it transitions to state S2 with probability P. From time to time it returns to S1, and then it can again transition to S2 with probability P.

Now, it is this P I am after. What I know is the following. I have a distribution of how many 'timesteps' the system stays in S1 before going to S2. So this is basically an array of the form [1 2 1 12 15 8 2].

So I know the distribution of how many times it does not transition, before doing so.

What I have thought of is that this is obviously a binomial distribution. However, the parameters of the distribution are not clear to me. It seems as if the number of repetitions N and the amount of times something happens k are constantly changing, depending on what value I take from my array. Is there a clever way to go about this?

Comment: I mean, I know how to find the related probabilities, as in the chance is 0.18 that it will take 4 timesteps until it occurs, etcetera. But I still don't see how to go from there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $P(S_1\rightarrow S_2)=p$ for each timestep that the system is in state $S_1$, then the number of turns that the system spends in $S_1$ before transitioning to $S_2$ will not have a binomial distribution, but a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p$.

You also have a vector of N elements, with each element indicating how many turns the system remains in $S_1$ before it goes to $S_2$ (i.e., if the first element in the vector is 2, then we know that at T=3 the system was in state $S_2$, correct?).

Therefore, your vector represents a sample of size N from a geometric distribution with parameter $p$.

The final insight into your problem is that each observation is independent, since the probability, $p$, doesn't change over time, therefore, each element in your vector of observations stands on its own, unaffected by the observations before or after it.

Taking all this together, you can apply the maximum likelihood estimate for a geometric random variable to your vector of observations, $\mathbf{x}:=\{x_1,x_2...x_N\} : \hat p_{MLE} = \frac{N}{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}$, which is just the total number of jumps from $S_1\rightarrow S_2$ divided by the total number of time periods the syatem was in state $S_1$..

Lets apply this to your example vector: [1 2 1 12 15 8 2]. The vector has 7 elements, so we observed N=7 jumps from $S_1\rightarrow S_2$. The total time the system was in $S_1$ during the observation period is the sum of the elements of the vector, which is 41 time periods. Therefore, you saw 7 transitions in 41 total time periods giving an estimated value for P of $\frac{7}{41} \approx \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that makes a lot of sense. Stupid that I didn't think of the geometric distribution!

Comment: Now I certainly haven't looked into this enough, and it has been a while since I have done any statistics, but what would be the wisest way of going about finding the 'error' in this estimate of p? Just repeat the experiment for, say, 50 datasets, calculate p every time and calculate the standard deviation of all those p's?

Comment: @user3183724 There are a number of methods out there, depending on how conservative you want to be. By error, I assume you would like an X% confidence interval for the true :p". One of the first was the Clopper-pearson confidence interval...it is very conservative but guarantees that you have at least X% coverage probability. I'd recommend the Wilson Score interval. You can see both on the wikipedia page for binomial distributions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval

Comment: Indeed, I'm talking about a suitable confidence interval. Now, I might just be very stupid, but I really can't find a version of the Wilson Score interval that is adapted to a geometric distribution, nor a general version from which I can derive it. Moreover, my search attempt for 'any' confidence interval for the geometric distribution is coming up empty..

Comment: @user3183724 see my response to your related question.

Comment: @user3183724 My suggestion for the Wilson Score above was based on the assumption that you did not intend to observe N geometric random variables (i.e., N transitions from S1 to S2), hence the sample size is variable in this case. I assumed you were observing the process for a certain number of time steps and then stopped it to analyze the data. The geometric/negative binomial/binomial inference question is actually a philosophically complex issues that gives differnet answers depending on different approaches (Bayesian/Frequentis/Likelihood)...quite tricky.